# sqlException (0x80131904) The name'...' is not a valid identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is dynamic based on what database it needs to access. Running the procedure from a program gives me an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The name '...' is not a valid identifier.....

When I run the stored procedure from SSMS, I get the same error, but if I print instead of exec, then run the code manually, it works perfectly fine.

```
declare @sql as varchar(8000)
if @Provider=''
    set @sql = '
    update  ' + @LinkServer + '.dbo.[billing header] set [Bill Primary]=1 where Billing in(
    select Distinct Billing from  ' + @LinkServer + '.dbo.[History Detail] 
    where ' +  @whereDateFacility  + ' and [insurance code] = rtrim( '''+ @PrimaryCode +'''));
select @@rowcount as rc;'
else
    set @sql = '
    update  ' + @LinkServer + '.dbo.[billing header] set [Bill Primary]=1 where Billing in(
    select Distinct hd.Billing from  ' + @LinkServer + '.dbo.[History Detail] hd
        inner join ' + @LinkServer + '.dbo.[billing header] bh on bh.billing=hd.billing
    where provider=''' + @Provider + ''' and ' +  @whereDateFacility  + ' and [insurance code] = rtrim( '''+ @PrimaryCode +'''));
select @@rowcount as rc;'
End

insert into dbo.[log] ([desc]) values(@sql)

--print @sql
exec @sql
```

Pulling the code snippet from the log also works fine too.
Here is the final code from the log that works fine if ran manually.

```
update [targetDb].dbo.[billing header] 
set [Bill Primary] = 1 
where Billing in (select Distinct Billing 
                  from [targetDb].dbo.[History Detail] 
                  where [Date printed] = '04/22/2014' 
                    and [insurance code] = rtrim( 'med001'));
select @@rowcount as rc;
```

Any ideas what can be done to fix this?

Thanks,
Dave K.

Comment: Does your program have the same access to the databases as your SSMS session?

Comment: yes it does. Other procedures ran from the program work using the same connection string, so I was thinking it was something related directly to the procedure and not a connection issue, right?

Comment: is the above update statement result of `print @sql`?

Comment: Ugh. Use `EXEC sp_executesql @sql;` or `EXEC(@sql);`.

Comment: Aaron, so simple, I feel so dumb right now... please make it an answer so I can mark it correct. Thanks!